# Query from a different database than the default

Tags: database, query, page-template

I'm making a layout for a wordpress page.

The layout needs to connect to a second database (both databases are in the same domain).

But the problem is, when i execute just the file it works. But when i included  inside the wordpress layout i don't get data, no errorrs, nothing

The script is just:

```
 $con = mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
 mysql_select_db('db', $con);
 $q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM vars', $con);
 var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($q));
```

As i say.
If i execute the file alone:

> http://example.com/blog/connect.php

it works great, and returns data.

But if i do inside the layout (creating a wordpress page, and giving the layout to it)
Returns nothing.

Any idea what can be happening there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why the mysql_connect isn't working inside WordPress. But an easier way of doing it would be to use the **$wpdb** class. Try replacing your code with this:

```
$second_db = new $wpdb( 'user', 'pass', 'dbname', 'host' );
$q = $second_db->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM vars' );
var_dump( $q );
```

and see if you get the results you want. *(note that the order of the variables passed to the `$wpdb` constructor is different from the order used by `mysql_connect`)*

Comment: And, just for the record, you should be using PHP PDO, not `mysql_`...which was designed LONG ago for MySQL4, which isn't even supported by wordpress anymore.

Comment: i'm trying now. This one works just as expected! thanks!

Comment: Set WPDB prefix to make WP_Query and get_post to generate correct sql query by calling `$wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');`

Answer (score 0):

goldenapples probably has the best solution, but to answer your question specifically, you need to set the `new_link` parameter in the `mysql_connect` function to `true`.

```
 $con = mysql_connect('host','user','pass', true);
```

Comment: I understand if you create 2 mysql_connect with the 3 params (no matters if them are differents) it return the same link? without that true.  I just gonna test tomorrow at work, if don't work i test the goldenapples solution too. thanks